# Projectile Set Relative to Ship Location Java

Tags: java, math, paint

I am working on making a Top-Down Shooter Clone in Java. After an hour or so, I was able to figure how to position the ship's projectile which is a laser relative to the direction of the ship's sprite. Problem is, if I move the ship, the projectile follows relative to the ship direction when I move the ship. As you can see this is a problem because the laser should be moving independently regardless of where the ship is when it is fired.

Here's the code which presents my problem:

```
private Image ship;
    private int ship_dx = 500;
    private int ship_dy = 400;
    private int ship_velocity = 5;
    private boolean isLaser = false;
    private static final int laser_DyOffSetOfBall = 48;
    private static final int laser_DxOffSetOfBall = 23;
    private Image laser;
    private int laser_dx = ship_dx+laser_DxOffSetOfBall;
    private int laser_dy = ship_dy-laser_DyOffSetOfBall;
    private int laser_velocity= 10;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(ship, ship_dx, ship_dy, this);
        if(isLaser){

            laser_dy -= laser_velocity;
            laser_dx = ship_dx+laser_DxOffSetOfBall;
            g.drawImage(laser,laser_dx,laser_dy,this);
            if(laser_dy < 50)
            {
                isLaser = false;
                laser_dy = ship_dy-laser_DyOffSetOfBall;
            }
        }
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
    }
```

Here's the game!:

[image: IMG]

Comment: Please copy and paste the code instead of using an image. That way we can run it and test it.

Comment: Please post code here, not as a image, to help who answer and also for future visitor

Comment: okay I changed from image to code. my apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to set the x location of the laser on the first time it is painted, because otherwise on every repaint, the laser moves horizontally relatively to the ship. To do this you can add another boolean isFirst (for the first paint of the laser), that is set to true when isLaser first turns to be true, and the x location is only set when isFirst is true.

```
boolean isFirst = true;

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(ship, ship_dx, ship_dy, this);
    if(isLaser){
        laser_dy -= laser_velocity;
        if(isFirst){

            laser_dx = ship_dx+laser_DxOffSetOfBall;
            isFirst = false;

        }
        g.drawImage(laser,laser_dx,laser_dy,this);
        if(laser_dy < 50)
        {
            isLaser = false;
            laser_dy = ship_dy-laser_DyOffSetOfBall;
        }
    } else {
        isFirst = true;
    }
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
}
```

Comment: I tried your code but surprisingly, the laser still follows the path of the ship. Your code makes sense but I think the code lies in laser_dx = ship_dx + laser_DxOffSetOfBall. The mathematical expression is good for setting the laser to the ship but as soon as the laser fires, it will still use the value of ship_dx+ laser_DxOffSetOfBall for variable laser_dx.

Comment: Sorry, my code was a bit erroneous, I just fixed it, and it should work now.

Answer (score 1):

The error is in line `laser_dy = ship_dy - ....`

You want to draw the projectile independent of the ships position, so then dont use ship_dy and ship_dy, instead store the projectile startPos in in seperate varable which will not changed during ship movement;

something like

```
laserStartX = ship_dx;
laserStartY = ship_dy;
```

and later:

```
laser_dx = laserStartX + laserDxOffsetBall;
```

same for laser_dy

Comment: but it will still use the value of ship_dx even if you assign it to laserStartX.